# Using the getVarCov function in base R

Tags: r

I want to obtain the estimate of the variance-covariance matrix of the response vector of a final linear mixed model, for a male adult (where Gender (G.F = 1). I am using the getVarCov () function. but how do i specify this in the "individual" part of the function please.

My code so far is this. G.f is the factored Gender,A is the age of adult less the mean age, W is the weight of adult less the mean weight and Adult.f is the factor variable that identify the adult in the study. The model is represented below.

```
Model1<-lme(C ~ A + W + G.f + A:W + A:G.f + W:G.f + A:W:G.f, random = ~  1 | Adult.f, weights = 
              varIdent(form = ~ 1 | G.f), method = "REML", data=Veneer)
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do this. G.f can either be 0 or 1 only

```
VarY_hat <- getVarCov(Model1, individual = c(G.f = 1), type = "marginal")[[1]]
VarY_hat
```

Comment: Neither `lme` nor `getVarCov` are in the base packages, state your `library`es please.

Comment: The packages are listed below. Sorry about that. 
library("plyr")
library("tidyverse")
library("nlme")
library("car")
library("hexbin")
library("xtable")
library("knitr")
library("Rcpp")
library("vctrs")
library("dplyr")
library("knitr")
library("multcomp")
library("lmerTest")

Comment: We don't really need these 13 packages for two functions, do we? Also since we don't have `Veneer` we are not able to reproduce your problem. Please read our tutorial on [minimal working examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038) and fix your question, thanks.